# react-native run-android build error after react-native link

Tags: react-native

```
ERROR: startup failed:
settings file 'C:\Users\ACER\Documents\project\react-native\app\android\settings.gradle': 3: unexpected char: '\' @ line 3, column 113.
   ode_modules\react-native-admob\android')
                                 ^
1 error
```

When `react-native link` is used it shows error in node module with every package, e.g: firebase, linear-gradient, admob etc.  any solution? I have tried everything i find out.

[image]

Comment: related to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54505023/10205629

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple problem to deal with, and it happens anytime you install packages and link them with `react-native link` on Windows. 
To solve this problem, just go to your `settings.gradle` file located at `YourApp\android\settings.gradle` the change all the backslashes `\` to forward slashes `/`.
so it should look like this:

```js
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
```

Good luck!